# Video and audio out of sync when playing 1080p 60fps on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-2, omxplayer, 1080p

I have a `1080p @ 60fps mp4` video saved in a external USB HDD. I've tried playing it on Raspbian in my Pi 2 (the new one, 1 GB RAM, 1 GHz) with Omxplayer, but the audio and video are out of sync. The audio plays at least a second ahead of the video, so it's pretty noticeable. Videos at `30 fps` seem to play fine and are correctly synced. I've tried memory splitting with up to `256 MB` for GPU, but the problem persists. I've seen other questions regarding this issue but no one seemed to end up being resolved.

Comment: Does it improve if you put the file on the SD Card?

Comment: I will try tomorrow. The external drive is entirely formated in NTFS.Could that have something to do?

Comment: It could be the result of latency on the USB bus.

Comment: Also, how are you outputting the audio?

Comment: Via HDMI. It also happened with "-o local", and whether I use "-p" or not.

Comment: It seems it's also happening with the file being on the SD card.

Comment: Update: Problem is still present using Kodi.

Comment: Was this solved? If not I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: The people suggesting this would have something to do with the storage media are overlooking that video files typically store the audio and associated video relatively close to each other.  The problem is thus going to be more about processing (decoding) bandwidth, not about getting at the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.These are my current settings related to this:

```
arm_freq=800
gpu_mem=128
h264_freq=350
force_turbo=1
core_freq=500
```

Haven't used it for video in a while, but last time I checked it played smooth and without any problem.

Comment: Please post your settings here and on the pi forum as there is no indication there that it was fixed - just to conversation. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not hesitate to post your findings here. It will make the answer way more useful for anybody else stumbling upon it later.

Comment: Edited answer with settings.